# Building an web app which can perform npm tasks

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

Before I post any configuration, I try to explain what I would like to archive and would like to mention, that I’m new to docker.

To make path conversations easier, let's assume we talk about the project "Docker me up!" and it's located in `X:\docker-projects\docker-me-up\`.

**Goal:**

I would like to run multiple nginx project with different content, each project represents a dedicated build. During development [`docker-compose up -d`] a container should get updated instantly; which works fine.

The tricky part is, that I want to outsource npm [http://gruntjs.com] from my host directly into the container/image, so I’m able to debug and develop wherever I am, by just installing docker. Therefore, npm must be installed in a “service” and a watcher needs to be initialized.

Each project is encapsulated in its own folder on the host/build in docker and should not be have any knowledge of anything else but itself.

**My solution:**

I have tried many different versions, with “volumes_from” etc. but I decided to show you this, because it’s minified but still complete.

*Docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx
        volumes:
            - ./assets:/website/assets:ro
            - ./config:/website/config:ro
            - ./www:/website/www:ro
        links:
            - php
    php:
        image: php:fpm
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        volumes:
            - ./assets:/website/assets:ro
            - ./config:/website/config:ro
            - ./www:/website/www:ro
    app:
        build: .
        volumes:
            - ./assets:/website/assets
            - ./config:/website/config:ro
            - ./www:/website/www
```

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM debian:jessie-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    npm

RUN gem update --system
RUN npm install -g grunt-cli grunt-contrib-watch grunt-babel babel-preset-es2015

RUN mkdir -p /website/{assets,assets/es6,config,www,www/js,www/css}

VOLUME /website

WORKDIR /website
```

**Problem:**

As you can see, the “data” service contains **npm** and should be able to execute a npm command. But, if I run `docker-compose up -d` everything works. I can edit the page content, work with it, etc. But the data container is not running and because of that cannot perform any npm command. Unless I have a huge logic error; which is quite possible ;-)

**Environment:**

- Windows 10 Pro [up2date]
- Shared drive for docker is used
- Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec
- docker-machine version 0.8.2, build e18a919
- docker-compose version 1.8.1, build 004ddae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you call `docker-compose up`, you can get an interactive shell for your `app` container with:

```
docker-compose run app
```

You can also run one-off commands with:

```
docker-compose run app [command]
```

The reason your `app` container is not running after `docker-compose up` completes is that your `Dockerfile` does not define a service. For `app` to run as a service, you would need to keep a thread running in the foreground of the container by adding something like:

```
CMD ./run-my-service
```

to the end of your Dockerfile.